# RDP connect to work computer

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, workgroup

I'm working from home, and i have a work laptop in my house, at the moment i have to switch the keyboard and mouse between my pc and the work laptop i was wondering if i can RDP to my work laptop from my pc, the work laptop is a work group i have an account to the work group and admin access to the Administrator account of the local account of the laptop, any suggestions?
I have tried connecting like a normal pc but it wont let me

Comment: Let's say you might be able to. But a KVM switch, or a virtual KVM like [Mouse Without Borders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/mouse-without-borders) sound like a much simpler solution

Comment: There are firewall rules that block this kind of thing by default. There are also other settings like VPN, workgroup policy or authentication methods that can give you trouble, so you should usually check with your work's IT.

Comment: It probably won't work but would depend on the system policies and configuration your IT department has applied. It also may be affected by any VPN software/configuration they have put on it. Personally, I use a KVM switch

Comment: I suggest trying it in the reverse order actually. Assuming you can access `mstc.exe` to make an RDP connection, see if you can RDP into your home PC (by IP Address) while it is connected to the VPN, then you can minimize and maximize it optionally rather than the other way around. This way you have more control over FW rules, `Remote Desktop Users`, and so forth from your personal machine. This could be impacted depending on routes pushed put on the laptop upon connecting to the VPN, split tunneling, etc. Might not be easily possible either way but won't know unless you try.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle how wold be the connection on the rdp?
[config](https://imgur.com/a/RiWQDsJ) is this how you would connect?

Comment: Yes, but with IP address of your home machine, and then `.\username` or `domain\username` perhaps. Same exact thing, RDP using `mstsc.exe` yes.

Comment: @YisroelTech thanks man, thats what i was looking for, i didnt know it existed i bought one last week and it works wonderfull, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct answer to your "issue", I think that you can have the outcome you want with much simpler methods.

You can buy a physical **KVM switch**, or a **virtual KVM** like [*Mouse Without Borders*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/mouse-without-borders).